# How to find invariant sets of nonlinear operators below

Tags: dynamic, fluid-dynamics

How to find invariant sets of nonlinear operators below.
$$x[n+1]=0.9∗y[n]^2/(y[n]+2)+x[n]∗(1−0.8/(1+x[n]))$$
$$y[n+1]=0.8∗x[n]/(1+x[n])+0.6∗y[n]$$

Answer (score 3):

```
Solve[{x == 9/10 y^2/(y + 2) + x (1 - 4/5/(1 + x)), 
       y == 4/5 x/(1 + x) + 3/5 y}, {x, y}]

(*    {{x -> 0, y -> 0},
       {x -> 4, y -> 8/5}}    *)
```

Note that $x=0,y=0$ is a stable solution and $x=4,y=1.6$ is an unstable solution. There's a third fixed point at $x=\infty,y=2$ that is not found with this `Solve`.

Comment: Not always stable. The approximation at point (0,0) depends on the initial point.  When the initial point is (x=10, y=5), it does not approach the point (0,0).

Comment: @Zafar yes you're right. There's also a stable fixed-point at infinity.

Comment: When the start point is (10.5), it approaches the point (+ infinity, 2).